# Co locate pods and persistent volumes in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, kubernetes-cluster

I have a kubernetes cluster spread across two zones, A and B. I am using nfs volumes for persistent storage. I have nfs volumes in both the zones. I am creating a stateful set of 2 replicas which will be spread across these zones (I used pod anti-affinity to achieve this). Now I want the pods in zone A to use the volumes in zone A and ones in zone B to use the volumes in zone B.

I can add labels to the persistent volumes and match the persistent volume claims with these labels. But how do I make sure that the pvc for a pod does not get bound to a pv in another zone?

Comment: How do you provision the PVs? If you're using dynamic volume provisioning with https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/ and I'm not mistaken that should solve the problem?

Comment: There is no dynamic provisioning support for NFS as of now. And I am not sure if this -> https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage is production ready.

Comment: Yup, sorry, my bad. There's https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs but likely not production ready ;)

Comment: Is there any workaraound to achieve this?

Comment: Hmmm, only thing I can think of right now is trying to see if you can use `nodeAffinity` (as described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) for it?

Comment: Do you use cloud provider environment to provision K8s cluster?

Comment: no. It is a local cluster created manually with kubeadm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to bind `persistent volume claims (PVCs)` to `persistent volumes (PVs)` and split Kubernetes pods across your cluster between two zones using the special built-in label `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone`. If you create volumes manually, it is possible to label them with `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone:zoneA` value, ensuring that pod is only scheduled to nodes in the same zone as the zone of the persistent volume.

For example, to set `label` for a Node and PV:

```
kubectl label node <node-name> failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=zoneA

kubectl label pv <pv-name> failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=zoneA
```

Find some useful information from official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/labels-annotations-taints/#failure-domainbetakubernetesiozone).

Comment: oh great. Thanks for this. I was using nodeAffinity and podAntiAffinity to achieve this. This seems so much simpler.