# Bind specific volume to deployment replicas

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes deployment with three replicas, each one in one AZ (eu-west-1a,eu-west-1b and eu-west-1c). I have three AWS EBS volumes (each one in a different AZ) that I want to attach to each replica.

I know I can attach the volume with volume type awsElasticBlockStore but, how can I match each volume to the replica matching the AZ?

Comment: You probably want a statefulset here.

Comment: but if you still want to use a deployment and not statefulset , use PVs as local volumes , as local volumes binds to nodes and then use node selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested above, you have below choices

1. Use statefulsets. then each replica would get independent storage volume
2. use local volumes ( supported on 1.14 and above )
3. There is a PR already to enable independent storage for each replica. follow the link
   https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/4211

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, you can map AWS EBS volumes within `failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone` built-in [label](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/labels-annotations-taints/#failure-domainbetakubernetesiozone), thus you don't need to make a local volumes accross [Statefulsets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/). It will give you a chance to bind persistent volume claims (PVCs) to persistent volumes (PVs) residing on the same node matching appropriate availability zone, as I've suggested in the separate Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441409/co-locate-pods-and-persistent-volumes-in-kubernetes/51481768#51481768).